# MVC3 - Automatic virtual collection (database savechanges)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

EDIT:

I have found the problem of why it doesn't see the changes
I changed the object that is bound with modelbinder. In that case it is not tracked by the context.

Hello

I have a problem with virtual ICollections in my application. Is it correct that EF automatically saves changes u make to entities?****

For example if i add an item to a list (add player to a team) it will work without using a repository and dbset to save it it the database?

I have something like this

```
    public int RayonId { get; set; }
    public String Rayonnaam { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Duivenmelker> Duivenmelkers { get; set; }

    public Rayon()
    {
           Duivenmelkers = new List<Duivenmelker>();

    }      


    public void AddMelker(Duivenmelker m)

    {
        Duivenmelkers.Add(m);
    }
```

The above code changes the List only locally. But doesn't save changes to the database.I can call a repository to add a new object directly to the database, but that's not the good way i think.

What could possibly be wrong that causes this not to work?****

***savechanges return 0 (thinks no changes are made)***

I have now added

```
            c.Vluchten.Attach(v);
            c.Entry(v).State = EntityState.Added;
```

This apparently works, still i don't know why the EF doesn't see the changes without explicitly telling him

Comment: If you have found the problem and a solution for **this question** please write it as an answer and accept your own answer. *"Now a new question..."* should really be a **new question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the bound object from your modelbinder, instead search for the object attached to the context and make the changes there. 
(Bound object isn't tracked by the EntityChangetracker)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `SaveChanges()`

Comment: I have tried this in controller aswell as the class itself. context.saveChanges() etc. It doesn't add to my database. I use objectcontextperhttprequest so it is not possible that i call this savechanges on the wrong context right? It doesn't give any errors, when i call entry.state on the object i get (IEntitychangetracker problem)